# How to parse out a string in reverse by using sql regular expressions

Tags: regex, netezza, nsregularexpression

I need to backtrace a string for a particular value to parse out. Is there any way to get the required output by using regular expressions.

```
;2N9XsPQQ;PARAMETER_STRING=
```

Required o/p : `2N9XsPQQ`

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by "backtrace" or "parse out a string in reverse."    From your sample all I can infer is that you want the value delimited by semicolons. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Dileep: if the solution proposed works for you please accept it or explain why it doesn't, i'll try to fix accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\;([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\;.*?\=
```

https://regex101.com/r/vC6nZ7/1

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple:

```
NSString *pattern = @"(?<=;).*(?=;)"; //or equivalent
```

will do the work for you.

Online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aU5hZ1/2)

**UPDATE**

On Netezza SQL the lookbehind is not available so try one of the alternative solutions:

```
# Tested on Postgresql (no Netezza, postgres derived db, available atm)
SELECT regexp_matches('123abc;2N9XsPQQ;PARAMETER_STRING=',';(.*);');
# OR
SELECT regexp_replace('123abc;2N9XsPQQ;PARAMETER_STRING=','.*;(.*);.*','\1');
```

Comment: i'm trying to parse out the string by using Netezza SQL. it is giving null for me. dldhhahddsahhgdgsagdjsdg5dcdsa5;2N9XsPQQ;PARAMETER_STRING=dsagD%SDBHSDBAHS^ this is like my string.

Comment: @Dileep: i cannot test against Netezza SQL, i've tested on Postgres (from which Netezza is derived). I'm pretty sure both methods are correct. Let me know